# How to SSR nested components or slotted content with vueonrails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am trying to add Vue.js components to a Ruby-on-Rails app with SSR support by using Hypernova and `vueonrails` helpers.

I am able to render a registered component with Hypernova from a view (`.html.erb`) by using this helper:

```html
<%= render_vue_component('HelloWorld', message: 'Hello World from SSR!') %>
```

Let's say my `HelloWorld` component has a `<slot>` in its template:

```
<template>
  <div class="helloworld">
    <h1>{{ message }}</div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to replicate something like the following in the `.html.erb` using `render_vue_component`:

```
<hello-world message="Hello World from SSR!">
  <hello-world>SSR Nested component</hello-world>
</hello-world>
```

How could I pass child elements to the `render_vue_component` helper so they get rendered by Hypernova?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I analyzed the repo and by looking at the it, I think you should use the `render_vue_component` only for rendering the root component, like the `main.js` when you start a project with [@vue/cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/):

```rb
<%= render_vue_component('App', { router }) %>
```

I came to this conclusion by analyzing the [vueonrails](https://github.com/vueonrails/vueonrails) source code.

If you look to the [render_vue_component function](https://github.com/vueonrails/vueonrails/blob/32e727cb581162db6cbb69b0146898a8d6294dc4/app/helpers/syntax_helper.rb#L30), it only takes the identifier and a data object, which internally calls `render_react_component`.

By this signature, it simply don't fit with [Vue's render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) signatures, which are `(element, children)` or `(element, attributes, children)`.

Maybe you find a better support by [opening an issue on the repo](https://github.com/vueonrails/vueonrails/issues).

But I'd think twice before using this project because there isn't any documentation so far and checking the [website](https://vueonrails.com/), seems like they are more focused in selling books about the project than creating a documentation.